# Controller RedirectToAction adds something extra to the url

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, routes

I have a MVC application where you have to fill in some data then go to the next page, fill in some stuff en etc.
On the second page there is also a button to go back to the first page.

The buttonclick goes to a method that creates a RedirectToAction that is returned.
The method recieves the action and controller name to be used with the RedirectToAction method.

```
      var redirectAction = RedirectToAction(next ? mdl.NextAction : mdl.PrevAction, next ? mdl.NextController : mdl.PrevController, new { encIds = mdl.Ids.EncryptedIds, extra = encActionInfo });
      return redirectAction;
```

Going from page 1 to page 2 is not a problem.
It's the going back part.

If you on page 1 (controller: EigenGegevens, action: EigenGegevens) and you go to the next page you get the url:

```
https://acc.client.com/client/Dekking/Dekking?encIds=bladiebla
```

This is ok.

Going back should give this url:

```
 https://acc.client.com/client/EigenGegevens/EigenGegevens?encIds=bladiebla
```

But it doesn't. It gives:

```
https://acc.client.com/client/client/EigenGegevens/EigenGegevens?encIds=bladiebla
```

As you can see, two times /client/

If I don't use RedirectToAction and create the url in a string like "/controller/action?encIds=bladiebla" I get this url:

```
https://acc.client.com/EigenGegevens/EigenGegevens?encIds=bladiebla
```

Also not the right one.

This is my RouteConfig:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
  routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

  routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Error",
    url: "Error/Error/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Error", action = "Error", id = UrlParameter.Optional }, namespaces: new[] { "client" }
  );

  routes.MapRoute(
      name: "Default",
      url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
      defaults: new { controller = "EigenGegevens", action = "EigenGegevens", id = UrlParameter.Optional }, namespaces: new[] { "client" }
  );


}
```

This is de button html:

```
<button class="btn btn-default btn-block" type="submit" formaction="@Url.Action("PreviousPage","Dekking")" formnovalidate="formnovalidate">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left marginR15"></span>
    @Txt.Get("rsGegevensWijzigen")
  </button>
```

It goes to controller "dekking" and action "PreviousPage".
This is the action:

```
public ActionResult PreviousPage(VmDekking mdl)
{
  return GotoPage(mdl, next: false, currentStap: Stap.Twee);
}
```

This is the GotoPage method:

```
 public ActionResult GotoPage<T>(T mdl, bool next, Stap currentStap, bool doeRedirect = false) where T : BaseView
{
  var currentAction = GetCurrentAction(currentStap);
  Tuple<string, string> error = null;

  error = mdl.View2Domein(next);

  if (next && (!ModelState.IsValid || error != null))
  {
    var errors = ModelState.Where(m => m.Value.Errors.Count() > 0).ToList();

    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, ModelState> err in errors)
    {
      ModelState.AddModelError(err.Key, err.Value.Errors[0].ErrorMessage);
    }

    return View(currentAction, mdl);
  }

  mdl.SetNavigation(currentStap);

  string encActionInfo = mdl.EncryptExtraInfo(next ? mdl.NextExtraActionInfo : mdl.PrevExtraActionInfo);
  var redirectAction = RedirectToAction(next ? mdl.NextAction : mdl.PrevAction, next ? mdl.NextController : mdl.PrevController, new { encIds = mdl.Ids.EncryptedIds, extra = encActionInfo });

  return redirectAction;
}
```

I also tried removing the namespace from the default route, but that didn't change anything.

In IIS the website is configured like: Client/client

Why do I get two /client/ in my url?

Where does the second one come from?

Comment: Can you show us more code on your attempt? How are you invoking your button click?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand it, but I got the problem resolved by adding an extra route to the routeconfig.

```
      routes.MapRoute(
      name: "Basis",
      url: "{controller}/{action}",
      namespaces: new[] { "client" }
  );
```